# C# Transform list from one type to another

Tags: c#, json, linq

I'm working on displaying some data onto a table with C# MVC 5 razor. The data I'm using (and cannot be changed) looks like this in JSON:

```
[
    {
        "Status": "New",
        "Denver": 2,
        "Seattle": 0,
        "New York": 3,
        "El Paso": 0
    },
    {
        "Status": "In Progress",
        "Denver": 1,
        "Seattle": 2,
        "New York": 5,
        "El Paso": 1
    },
    {
        "Status": "Closed",
        "Denver": 12,
        "Seattle": 2,
        "New York": 1,
        "El Paso": 3
    }
]
```

Which resolves to this table:

```
+-------------+--------+---------+----------+---------+
|   Status    | Denver | Seattle | New York | El Paso |
+-------------+--------+---------+----------+---------+
| New         |      2 |       0 |        3 |       0 |
| In Progress |      1 |       2 |        5 |       1 |
| Closed      |     12 |       2 |        1 |       3 |
+-------------+--------+---------+----------+---------+
```

I'm deserializing this json into a list of objects, but can't get the formatting changed. I want the table to look like this in the view:

```
+----------+-----+-------------+--------+
|          | New | In Progress | Closed |
+----------+-----+-------------+--------+
| Denver   |   2 |           1 |     12 |
| Seattle  |   0 |           2 |      2 |
| New York |   3 |           5 |      1 |
| El Paso  |   0 |           1 |      3 |
+----------+-----+-------------+--------+
```

I've tried multiple for loops and linq selects, but not able to get it.
Here's what I've got:

```
public class Response {
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int Denver { get; set; }
    public int Seattle { get; set; }
    public int NewYork { get; set; }
    public int ElPaso { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int New { get; set; }
    public int InProgress { get; set; }
    public int Closed { get; set; }
}

List<Response> response = service.GetData();
if (response != null) {
    List<ViewModel> viewModels = response.Select(???);
}

return viewModels;
```

Somebody please point me in the right direction with this select statement. Thank you!

Comment: is the set of cities fixed? or can it change?

Comment: 2 - 3 city names may be added or removed, but that will only happen once a year so it's okay to plan on being fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you will always have the same set of cities, you could do:

```
var data = response.ToDictionary(x => x.Status, x => x);

var viewModels = new []
{
  new  ViewModel { Name = "Denver", New = data["New"].Denver, InProgress=data["In Progress"].Denver, Closed = data["Closed"].Denver },
  new  ViewModel { Name = "Seattle", New = data["New"].Seattle, InProgress=data["In Progress"].Seattle, Closed = data["Closed"].Seattle },
  new  ViewModel { Name = "New York", New = data["New"].NewYork, InProgress=data["In Progress"].NewYork, Closed = data["Closed"].NewYork },
  new  ViewModel { Name = "El Paso", New = data["New"].ElPaso, InProgress=data["In Progress"].ElPaso, Closed = data["Closed"].ElPaso }
}
```